# Data manipulation for sampling with replacement

Tags: r, data-manipulation, resampling

By comparison to most on this site, I am an extreme newbie when it comes to R, and would appreciate any possible help. I am looking to sample my data with replacement, but given how my data is set up, I am not sure how to go about that. I have 11 plant species. For each species I took 5 plant cuttings, and sampled 10 leaves from each cutting totaling 50 leaves per plant species. I need to sample with replacement within species. I was looking at using the sample function for this, but considering I need to sample within species I am not sure if I can. Attached is a photo of my data for context.

Data image

[image]

Apologies in advance for the naivety of my question and thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Hi. Welcome to stackoverflow. Please try to provide a sample of your data using `dput(head(data))` as an example instead of screenshots. I

Comment: Images are not the right way to share data/code. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Similar to jsfiddle, you can try https://tio.run/#r to share your code.
Here is an example: https://tio.run/##K/r/PyWxJFHBRldBPS8xN1UnMT1VpyqzgCsrPyNPx9AIiIxNTLmyMnNydIyMdUAcM6Bcqo6xiQ6Iba7OxZWSBtJelJqYopdcXKZRklpRYgsyVJOLq6AoM69EIyVN8/9/AA

Answer (score 1):

you can group by and then sample. This is assuming you have 5 cuttings per species. If not you may want to remove this condition from the group by

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(species, cutting) %>% 
  slice_sample(weight_by = `leaf size`, n=10, replace = TRUE) %>% 
  ungroup()
```